# How to select newest record from two tables SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to select newest record from two tables using SQL?

```
"select * from Table1,Table2 WHERE Date=(SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Table1,Table2)"

 -----------    -------------
|   table1  |  |   table2    |
 -----------    -------------
 -----------    -------------
|   title   |  |   title     |
 -----------    -------------
|   text    |  |   text      |
 -----------    -------------
|   date    |  |   date      |
 -----------    -------------
```

Comment: What is the expected output from that? The one latest record from either table 1 or 2. 2 records (that last from table1 and the last from table2) or perhaps even 1 record with 2 titles, 2 text and 2 dates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM Table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Table_2
) 
AS ALL_RECORDS
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: Although, you really should avoid the * and instead select the columns you need . . .

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
with tmp(title, text, date) as
(
select title, text, date from table1
union 
select title, text, date from table2
)
select top 1 * from tmp
order by date desc
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Andreas Rohde beat me to it. +1

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FTOM Table1, Tble2... creates a cross join (cartesian product of two sets of records) so ther will be multiple records with the same date. You have to specify more criteria to get only one record, and probably use some join. 
If you want to choose one record from two tables, where for example Table1 has the newer record than Table2, I think it will be good idea to use union, e.g.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, ..., coln max(Date) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Table1 UNION
    SELECT * FROM Table2
) GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, ..., coln
ORDER BY Date;
```